# Have public channels visible to all non admin users and forbid user from creating channels

Tags: rocket.chat

How can I have the existing public channels visible to all users ?

How can I forbid users (non admin) from creating channels ?

Version: 0.49.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I handled this was to create two main channels (Lobby and Announcements) for all of my employees.

I then used the REST API to add all users to those two channels. This won't prevent them from leaving the channels, but you could simply call the API every so often to add people back in that left (or new users, if setting the Default channel to True under Rooms in Administration doesn't seem to be working).

Here's the steps to do this, using curl:

1. Get your authentication Token and UserId [1]
2. Use your Token and Id from step 1 to get the full channel list [2]
3. Take the desired roomId from step 2 and (as well as using your Token and Id from step 1) use the addAll API [3] to add *literally all users* to the channel.

For the second one, you can use the Permissions [4] tab under Administration, it is "create-c" for public or "create-p" for private.

I can't post more than two links, so..

[1] httpx://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/authentication/login

[2] httpx://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/channels/list

[3] https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/channels/addall

[4] https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/permissions/